# How to know the required scene required to cover an area?

Tags: imagery

I want to know how to find the nos. of scene of LISS 4 data required to cover an area(say 84000 sq km)? any suggestion/solution/calculation?

Answer (score 1):

From this [page](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/data-access/browse-data-products?p_p_id=101_INSTANCE_s86V&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-4&p_p_col_count=4&_101_INSTANCE_s86V_struts_action=/asset_publisher/view_content&_101_INSTANCE_s86V_urlTitle=liss-iv-data-products-1661&_101_INSTANCE_s86V_type=content&p_r_p_564233524_assetIdentifier=liss-iv-data-products-1661&redirect=/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=66541):

> Standard Based and Geo Referenced products cover an area of 23 x 23 km
> (3Mx bands) and 70 x 70 km (Mono mode). Basic Stereo products are
> Radiometrically corrected and cover an area of 70 x 70 km (Mono mode).

So, mono mode: 70km x 70km = 4900km^2 per scene.
Multispectral mode: 23km x 23km = 529km^2 per scene.

So, to determine how many scenes are required to cover 84,000km^2:

For monochromatic:

84,000 / 4900 = 17.14 = 18 scenes.

For multispectral:

84,000 / 529 = 158.79 = 159 scenes.

I'm not very familiar with this dataset but that is how I would calculate the number of scenes required for any dataset.  Of course, it depends on the actual layout of the study area.  You may need slightly more or slightly less scenes.